# documentwrite SQL database while preserving the structure, in order to be able to print the database on paper

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have made a localhost server with wamp, and i want to be able to print out the entire database. I thought of the hacky solution of just documentwriting the entire database with all the values then just print the page. However, I have no idea how to show the database content on the html page while preserving the tables and structure of the database. I tried this:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','varer');

$data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM lagerbeholdning_hth");


while ( $tables = $result->fetch_array())
{
    echo $tmp[0]."<br>";
}
?>
```

but it didn't work. I also tried this while loop instead:

```
while ( $tables =  mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
   echo $tables["VARENUMMER"] . "<br>";
}
```

which posts all the correct values, but not properly formatted. Is there any way to do this, in another way perhaps? or a way to format the outputs properly so they are displayed according to database structure? or just plain print out the database from SQL.

Comment: What is `$tmp`? Should that be `$tables`?

Comment: What is `$result`, shouldn't that be `$data`? You're really confused about your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var_dump()` to print a structured representation of an array.

I recommend you use `fetch_assoc()`, which returns an associative array, so you'll see the column names.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM lagerbeholdning_hth");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code the display of the entire database contents, you will have a lot of work to do.  Displaying just the tables for a single database, you could write a select statement on the information_schema.TABLES to get the table names:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name';
```

Once you have the table name, you can then get the column names using the following query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
AND table_schema = 'db_name'
```

Once you have the table name and column information, you can then use this information to get the tables data and display it in an html table.